# how do I fill na values when I unstack more than one level at a time

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the `pd.Series` `s` with `pd.MultiIndex` `mux`

```
lol = [list('aabc'), list('xyyz'), [1, 2, 3, 3]]
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(lol, names='l1 l2 l3'.split())
s = pd.Series(range(1001, 1005), mux)

s

l1  l2  l3
a   x   1     1001
    y   2     1002
b   y   3     1003
c   z   3     1004
dtype: int64
```

According to the [documentation for `unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

> **fill_value** : replace NaN with this value if the unstack produces
>   missing values

And when I `unstack`

```
s.unstack()

l3          1       2       3
l1 l2                        
a  x   1001.0     NaN     NaN
   y      NaN  1002.0     NaN
b  y      NaN     NaN  1003.0
c  z      NaN     NaN  1004.0
```

I do get `NaN`s.
So I try `fill_value=0`

```
s.unstack(fill_value=0)

l3        1     2     3
l1 l2                  
a  x   1001     0     0
   y      0  1002     0
b  y      0     0  1003
c  z      0     0  1004
```

Sure enough, the `NaN`s were filled with `0`.

However, if I want to `unstack` more that one level at a time.

```
s.unstack(['l2', 'l3'], fill_value=0)

l2       x       y               z
l3       1       2       3       3
l1                                
a   1001.0  1002.0     NaN     NaN
b      NaN     NaN  1003.0     NaN
c      NaN     NaN     NaN  1004.0
```

My `fill_value` is ignored.

***Why?  And what is a work around?***

Comment: what's wrong with `s.unstack(['l2', 'l3']).fillna(0)`?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, it's probably failing to handle the reindexing needed for the multiple levels that are unstacked, of course you can chain a call to `fillna(0)` after but the dtypes are now upcasted to float from the initial failure in filling the value in the first place, I'd file a bug on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: @MaxU the dtypes get converted to float due to the presence of `NaN` if `fill_value` had worked it would remain as int

Comment: @MaxU what's wrong is that in that step of unstacking, it converts to float.  Subsequently filling in with zero, they are still floats.  You have to cast to int to keep ints if that's what they were.

Comment: ok, thanks, got it now

Comment: I think the "problematic" function is `pandas.core.reshape.__unstack_multiple` - you'll have the same behaviour if you try this: `s.unstack(['l2'], fill_value=0)`

Comment: @MaxU please put an answer here so I can up vote it and accept it.

Comment: @piRSquared, thank you! just added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [3]: s.unstack(['l2', 'l3']).fillna(0)
Out[3]:
l2       x       y               z
l3       1       2       3       3
l1
a   1001.0  1002.0     0.0     0.0
b      0.0     0.0  1003.0     0.0
c      0.0     0.0     0.0  1004.0
```

Answer (score 1):

***@MaxU's work around***
Makes the most sense.  Just `fillna(0)` and change `dtype`

```
s.unstack(['l2', 'l3']).fillna(0).astype(s.dtype)
```

***terrible work around***
Very wasteful!

- Do `unstack` the way I'd like to just to capture the columns
- Do multiple single unstacks with `fill_value=0` and reindex with columns from prior step.

---

```
cols = s.unstack(['l2', 'l3']).columns
s.unstack('l2', fill_value=0).unstack('l3', fill_value=0).reindex_axis(cols, 1)
```

***better work around***
Only works in this special case.

Unstack the one level I didn't care about with `fill_value=0` then transpose

```
s.unstack(0, fill_value=0).T
```

---

All solutions produce

```
l2     x     y           z
l3     1     2     3     3
l1                        
a   1001  1002     0     0
b      0     0  1003     0
c      0     0     0  1004
```